# Why My Request turn post to option with Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, cross-domain

Why I got this first CORS and then Post request auto turn into OPTION,

I run this on my local with just button click , When first I get the CORS I added header as well you can see in below code.

```
var postData2= {
            "input_text": "انسان سب سے بڑی غلطی اس وقت کرتا ہے جب وہ اللہ کی طرف سے دی گئی ڈھیل کو اس کا کرم سمجھنے لگتا",
            "output_lang": "ENG",
            "name": "zahid",
            "contact": "4646468"
        }
        console.log(postData2);
        let axiosConfig = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            }
          };

        axios.post('http://95.217.98.30:8000/u2r/convert', postData2 , axiosConfig)
        .then((res) => {
        console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
        })
```

I got this error in my console

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://95.217.98.30:8000/u2r/convert' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code. It's a browser level security enabled to restrict the response being received from other domains. Though you add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" in your request header, it will not resolve your problem. The same header should be added to your response header. This should be done from your server-side code. Please go through the below page to implement it in your server-side.
https://enable-cors.org/server.html